# bash syntax error report format (basic)

Tags: shell, syntax

Newish to shell scripting I've noticed that the syntax error report for an unexpected token has the format

```
`unexpectedtoken' # ie backtick unexpected_token singlequote
```

What do the backtick and the single quote represent? They're not present in the script itself.
They're something to do with the shell, but what?

More specifically, I'm currently getting two error reports from the same line, which should be helping my debug attempts but I don't know how to interpret them. The script has a param being passed to a function.

```
append2file \
"(common params for all samples; exemplar: ${monoArr2[@]:(-1)})"
```

The first paren on the param line (line154) is the unexpected token. This also triggers a second error report.

```
./process_v7.sh: line 154: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./process_v7.sh: line 154: `        "(common params for all read_2 samples; exemplar: ${monoArr2[@]:(-1)})" \'
```

The spacing between the leading backtick and the start of that double-quoted string must be telling me something that will help my debugging, but what??? TIA

M

Comment: The code you have above is fine, assuming there is no whitespace after the \ on line 153, and that line 152 does not end with a \.  The syntax error is probably caused by code in lines 140-152.  Show more.

Comment: solved! I used vi to search back from line154 for double_quotes and found a stray one earlier in the script. Thanks for the hint William.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for defining a function is:

```
append2file() {
   # some code that references parameters via $1, $*, $@, etc
}
```

It sounds like you are putting something inside the ().  Don't do that.

Comment: @ WPursell: thanks, the function is defined OK, but the call does admittedly look misleading; it's passing in a string param that itself includes enclosing parens. So misleading though the call looks it's actually OK.